# How breeze.js does sync? does it download all the server data eveytime and compare?

Tags: html, caching, breeze, synchronization, single-page-application

I am trying to use breeze.js in my SPA application but I am having difficulty understanding the way it works. I have tried to add alerts on onSuccess function and what I can see that it fetches all the records form the online database. It this true? I believe there is some sort of change tracking mechanism that should identify the records changed online and only download those? I can see that happening on the local cache but does something similar happens on the server side (remote data) as well. otherwise this will be a big bandwidth overhead and unusable in large datasets.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The results of a query are determined entirely by the server's response to the client request. If you query for all customers, that's what you get.

Breeze does not have a mechanism for detecting when and which records have changed in your remote data source. That's something only the server can do. You'll have to come up with a mechanism that fits your business need and is supported by your server technology.

It's a big topic and an interesting one. Too broad for a one-size-fits-all reply here I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks. but doesn't that puts breeze out of context for mobile app as such behavior will incur extensive bandwidth usage.. If one have to implement a server side logic that whats the point of using breeze in that case? Any other suggested alternates?

Comment: I agree that continually pulling down content that hasn't changed is painful, especially for mobile (with data charges).  Breeze solves many other client-side data management challenges; just not this one. This S.O. question is the wrong place to review value points which are covered copiously elsewhere. A web search is your friend. What would I do? I'd look into an out-of-band push technology to tell my client when and what entities to refresh. That's the same answer I'd give, with or without Breeze. Good luck.